# WordPress Custom Sidebar, Pass Unique ID

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress documentation is quite clear https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'theme_slug_widgets_init' );
function theme_slug_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'theme-slug' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
```

The code above would work perfectly fine, without any issues. However, in my case, I want to pass the unique ID to the `h2` tag (before_title). placing simple `id="%1$s"` doesn't seem to work as there might be some preprocessing which is done with `before_widget`.

```
'before_title'  => '<h2 id="%1$s" class="widgettitle">',
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: > "Doesn't seem to work" means Sidebar doesn't show in wp-admin Widgets area?
 OR  When you call using do_sideabr function?

Comment: It doesnt pass the unique ID with `'before_title'  => '<h2 id="%1$s" class="widgettitle">',
` as it passes on with `'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
`

Comment: @prakashchhetri you can directly pass the id in the `h2` tag like `before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title" id="your-id">`

Comment: @KrupalPanchal i want the id to be unique. So I am trying to access the unique widget id.

Comment: @prakashchhetri if you want to give unique id then take the id which not used in site anywhere.

Comment: how about use jquery(javascript) after page load? did you tried ?

Answer (score -2):

You need to make some changes to the WordPress default function. Please check this Solution.

File Path:- `wp-includes/widgets.php`

Find function `dynamic_sidebar` and add this code

`$params[0]['before_title'] = sprintf($params[0]['before_title'], $id, $classname_);`

after this line

`params[0]['before_widget'] = sprintf($params[0]['before_widget'], $id, $classname_);`

**Edit**

**Note:** This code will be removed when WordPress Update.

**-------------------------------------------------------------------**

**UPDATE**

Please Add this function `function.php`

```
function dynamic_sidebar_customize($index = 1) {
global $wp_registered_sidebars, $wp_registered_widgets;

if (is_int($index)) {
    $index = "sidebar-$index";
} else {
    $index = sanitize_title($index);
    foreach ((array) $wp_registered_sidebars as $key => $value) {
        if (sanitize_title($value['name']) == $index) {
            $index = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
}

$sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
if (empty($wp_registered_sidebars[$index]) || empty($sidebars_widgets[$index]) || !is_array($sidebars_widgets[$index])) {
    /** This action is documented in wp-includes/widget.php */
    do_action('dynamic_sidebar_before', $index, false);
    /** This action is documented in wp-includes/widget.php */
    do_action('dynamic_sidebar_after', $index, false);
    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widget.php */
    return apply_filters('dynamic_sidebar_has_widgets', false, $index);
}

/**
 * Fires before widgets are rendered in a dynamic sidebar.
 *
 * Note: The action also fires for empty sidebars, and on both the front end
 * and back end, including the Inactive Widgets sidebar on the Widgets screen.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 *
 * @param int|string $index       Index, name, or ID of the dynamic sidebar.
 * @param bool       $has_widgets Whether the sidebar is populated with widgets.
 *                                Default true.
 */
do_action('dynamic_sidebar_before', $index, true);
$sidebar = $wp_registered_sidebars[$index];

$did_one = false;
foreach ((array) $sidebars_widgets[$index] as $id) {

    if (!isset($wp_registered_widgets[$id])) {
        continue;
    }

    $params = array_merge(
        array(array_merge($sidebar, array('widget_id' => $id, 'widget_name' => $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['name']))),
        (array) $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['params']
    );

    // Substitute HTML id and class attributes into before_widget
    $classname_ = '';
    foreach ((array) $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['classname'] as $cn) {
        if (is_string($cn)) {
            $classname_ .= '_' . $cn;
        } elseif (is_object($cn)) {
            $classname_ .= '_' . get_class($cn);
        }

    }
    $classname_ = ltrim($classname_, '_');
    $params[0]['before_widget'] = sprintf($params[0]['before_widget'], $id, $classname_);

    $params[0]['before_title'] = sprintf($params[0]['before_title'], $id, $classname_);

    /**
     * Filters the parameters passed to a widget's display callback.
     *
     * Note: The filter is evaluated on both the front end and back end,
     * including for the Inactive Widgets sidebar on the Widgets screen.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @see register_sidebar()
     *
     * @param array $params {
     *     @type array $args  {
     *         An array of widget display arguments.
     *
     *         @type string $name          Name of the sidebar the widget is assigned to.
     *         @type string $id            ID of the sidebar the widget is assigned to.
     *         @type string $description   The sidebar description.
     *         @type string $class         CSS class applied to the sidebar container.
     *         @type string $before_widget HTML markup to prepend to each widget in the sidebar.
     *         @type string $after_widget  HTML markup to append to each widget in the sidebar.
     *         @type string $before_title  HTML markup to prepend to the widget title when displayed.
     *         @type string $after_title   HTML markup to append to the widget title when displayed.
     *         @type string $widget_id     ID of the widget.
     *         @type string $widget_name   Name of the widget.
     *     }
     *     @type array $widget_args {
     *         An array of multi-widget arguments.
     *
     *         @type int $number Number increment used for multiples of the same widget.
     *     }
     * }
     */
    $params = apply_filters('dynamic_sidebar_params', $params);

    $callback = $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['callback'];

    /**
     * Fires before a widget's display callback is called.
     *
     * Note: The action fires on both the front end and back end, including
     * for widgets in the Inactive Widgets sidebar on the Widgets screen.
     *
     * The action is not fired for empty sidebars.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param array $widget_id {
     *     An associative array of widget arguments.
     *
     *     @type string $name                Name of the widget.
     *     @type string $id                  Widget ID.
     *     @type array|callable $callback    When the hook is fired on the front end, $callback is an array
     *                                       containing the widget object. Fired on the back end, $callback
     *                                       is 'wp_widget_control', see $_callback.
     *     @type array          $params      An associative array of multi-widget arguments.
     *     @type string         $classname   CSS class applied to the widget container.
     *     @type string         $description The widget description.
     *     @type array          $_callback   When the hook is fired on the back end, $_callback is populated
     *                                       with an array containing the widget object, see $callback.
     * }
     */
    do_action('dynamic_sidebar', $wp_registered_widgets[$id]);

    if (is_callable($callback)) {
        call_user_func_array($callback, $params);
        $did_one = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Fires after widgets are rendered in a dynamic sidebar.
 *
 * Note: The action also fires for empty sidebars, and on both the front end
 * and back end, including the Inactive Widgets sidebar on the Widgets screen.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 *
 * @param int|string $index       Index, name, or ID of the dynamic sidebar.
 * @param bool       $has_widgets Whether the sidebar is populated with widgets.
 *                                Default true.
 */
do_action('dynamic_sidebar_after', $index, true);

/**
 * Filters whether a sidebar has widgets.
 *
 * Note: The filter is also evaluated for empty sidebars, and on both the front end
 * and back end, including the Inactive Widgets sidebar on the Widgets screen.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 *
 * @param bool       $did_one Whether at least one widget was rendered in the sidebar.
 *                            Default false.
 * @param int|string $index   Index, name, or ID of the dynamic sidebar.
 */
return apply_filters('dynamic_sidebar_has_widgets', $did_one, $index);
```

}

And update your `sidebar.php` file this function

```
dynamic_sidebar_customize('sidebar-1');
```

Now If your WordPress updates this code will not update.

Comment: it will be removed after wordpress update. so we need another solution

Comment: @AliQorbani:- If have you the better solution then, please post it will help to others